# Android: Navigation bar is hiding when keyboard opens

Tags: android

I have a dialog that starts within a Service that contains several EditTexts. My issue is that when an EditText gets focus, the keyboard appears and the navigation bar disappears. Is there a way to prevent the navigation bar from disappearing?

This is the dialog code (from inside the service):

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    _view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_notif, null);

    _edit_1 = (EditText) _view.findViewById(R.id.edit1);
    _edit_2 = (EditText) _view.findViewById(R.id.edit2);

    _dial = new Dialog(this);
    _dial.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    _dial.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0x66000000));
    _dial.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR);
    _dial.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
    _dial.setContentView(_view);
    _dial.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    _dial.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface)
        {
            stopSelf();
        }
    });
    _dial.show();

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: Before and After: Navigation Bar Hidden by Keyboard]

Comment: `_dial.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);` this seems a bit mysterious to me

Answer (score 1):

you are creating `Dialog` using context of `Service`:

```
_dial = new Dialog(this);
```

which is strongly UNrecomended. your navigation bar is hiding probably because of theming/styling of `Dialog`. Consider starting new `Activity`, which will have [custom dialog-like-style](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme)